# Find a tangent line of a given parabola perpendicular to another given line

Tags: derivatives, curves

**The question from my textbook:**

> Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y = x²-2x$ that is perpendicular to the line $x-2y = 1$

- The derivative of the parabola: $2x-2$
- It's normal slope of the tangent: $-2$

**I thought of doing**

1.

$-2x-2 = \frac x 2 - \frac 1 2$

$-2.5 x + 1.5 = 0$

Root : $\frac 35 = 0.6$

then

$y-0 = -2 (x-0.6)$
$y = -2x -0.6$

but is clearly false and the right answer would be $y = -2x$ but how to find it?

2.
(I also thought of doing $-2 = 2x - 2$, then it would explain the $0$ for x-axis and for y-axis if insert to the parabola, is it the right way to do it?)

Can someone help me? I would love to know the steps behind the resolution of the problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Tangent is perpendicular to the given line. When two given lines are perpendicular, what's the product of their slopes?

Comment: no sorry, my mistake, the perpendicular line is not given, we need to find the tangent of the parabola that is perpendicular to another line

Comment: Can you elaborate the first step you did?

Comment: The later thought you have is absolutely correct.  What doubt are you encountering while proceeding with that thought process?

Comment: THANKS @AbhinavLenka, my textbook answer was incorrect and I was also thinking about: "How to make an equation that represent 2 intersections between different curves?", like equation1 = equation2 = equation3 or something similar. But I never saw something like this so